# FLEX - Disable mousescroll for scrollbars?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm looking for a way to disable the scrolling of the vertical and horizontal scrollbars when scrolling the mouse.

I use the mouse scroll to zoom in and out, and I don't want the scrollbars to scroll while scrolling the mouse wheel..
(But I do need the scrollbars to be visible).

Any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: U mean for whole application ??? or particular component ???

Comment: For the DividedBox component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DivideBoxID].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL,mouseWheelHandler);

public function mouseWheelHandler():void
{
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following one i am not sure but it might be work.

I am modifying the code its a bit of cheat with the code so i am not sure that i will work but just try this one.

```
[DivideBoxID].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL,mouseWheelHandler);


public function mouseWheelHandler():void
{
    //Leave this space blank..  
}
```

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property mouseWheelHandler through a reference with static type Test_tree_001. Test_tree_001.mxml /vCog Flash 14-12-2011 - SWF/src line 275 Flex Problem

Comment: It's not working mate. Thanks for your help though! Any other ideas? I just don't want the scrollbars to move while scrolling. Only when click'd and dragged... =)

Comment: Hi, Try to override the mouseWheelHandler function. so now you need to write override protected function..... 
Try that one..

Comment: that's just going to add another listener to the wheel event, not prevent it from happening.

Comment: change the access modifier from public to protected and still not done then override that method with following syntax. override protected function...